# logging in with accounts-ui-angular doesn't refresh $account.currentUser

Tags: javascript, angularjs, meteor, angular-ui-router

I am using the `dotansimha:accounts-ui-angular` directive in a page to login with an api service such as google. In the page I have a div with an `ng-show="$auth.currentUser"` which will hide the div if there isn't a signed in user present. The code works great, however I have to refresh the page. Currently I am embedding the `<login></login>` tags in the home index.html page. How can I make the $auth.currentUser value actively check for it's value ?

Answer (score 0):

So I ended up solving the problem, but I don't know if this is best practice.

In my html I want to hide two links if a user isn't signed in. I use `ng-show="$auth.currentUser"`

In my toolbar directive I added $watch logic that watches for a change in the `$auth.currentUser` value.

```
  $scope.$watch('currentUser',function(newVal, oldVal){
    console.log(newVal, oldVal)
    if(newVal !== oldVal || typeof newVal !== typeof {}){
      location.reload()
      Meteor.loginWithSpotify(options, function(err){
        console.log(err || 'No error')
      }
    }
    console.log(newVal, oldVal)
  })
```

This logic will reload the page if the value of $auth.currentUser isn't equal to value of $auth.currentUser or if the $auth.currentUser isn't typeof object, which when is authorized currentUser is an object.

**EX: if (user data !== null){ refresh page }**

Hope this is clear.